# Possible to build an editable site in just HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

A local nonprofit needs a new website. It's a very basic website that simply presents information, nothing past basic HTML/CSS is needed to make the actual site.

The marketing manager would like to be able to edit text sections (upcoming events, jobs) regularly. How would I go about creating the site in HTML/CSS and then allowing them to edit just the text in those sections in an easy way? is that even possible, or would this require more advanced knowledge of actual programming/database languages?

Thanks

Comment: You will need at least *some* server-side component here. You can't simply futz around in the browser and it will magically reflect on all other browsers of your visitors, without being able to save the changes on the server.

Comment: You could potentially use a content management system such as wordpress or magento or even something heavier like IBM portal.  There will have to be some sort of server side management system though.

Comment: Yes, I would try Wordpress.

Comment: @S.Morgenstern I don't think the question itself is too broad, since it can be easily answered as "it's not possible, here's why". However, explaining how to set up a CMS *would* be too broad.

Comment: You need to use a Content Management System (CMS).

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't edit the site with just HTML and CSS. Even if you have JavaScript, you'll need server side code (ASP.NET, PHP, Ruby on Rails, Node.js etc) to store the changed text, since HTML, CSS, and JS run on the client (excluding server side JavaScript based frameworks).

The easy solution is to just use simple HTML and tell him to directly edit the HTML. If he's just a little bit technical, an hour or two of explanation of how HTML works might be enough to get you going.

A [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) solution that is prebuilt and has simple menus for editing things might work nicely. There's plenty of various options to suit your needs.

Otherwise, you can either build a custom site. A custom site that reads text from simple text files might be all it takes ([Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) might be preferable to plain text.) Of course, you can scale it up if you want until you've basically built your own CMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

HTML pages are stored on a server (which is just a computer accessible by other computers via an internet connection), when you type in an address in your browser's address bar it sends a request to a server to fetch the corresponding HTML page. Then this page is displayed in your browser.

Now, say you managed to change a text in your browser somehow using HTML/CSS, but you still need to find a way to send these changes back to the server so that these updated pages are accessible by other remote browsers, and the only way of doing this is to use server side languages. They are not really that difficult, you can quickly learn that.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to take a look at this [sourceforge project.](http://sf.net/projects/hyperframe)

This is a file-based system that uses conventional HTML for the webpages, but allows online editing with CKEditor. Requirements are Apache 2 and php 5.3 or later.

There is a [testdrive](http://hyperframe.esy.es?login=guest) available. 
Login with guest.